# in the team vs. on the team

Tags: prepositions, american-english

In AmE, you only use the proposition 'on' with nouns that refer to groups of people ('team', 'board', 'commission', etc). Am I right?

Can I use 'in' without sounding like a weirdo or, at least, a foreigner (for the purposes of this question, we put the accent aside)? Is it mandatory or just an option? If for some reason you need an example sentence, here it is:

> Mr. Smith is **on** the team/board/commission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be very leery about using the word ***only*** when giving rules about English.

You wrote:

> you only use the proposition 'on' with nouns that refer to groups of people

The three example nouns you provided – *team, board, commission* – indeed typically use *on* instead of *in*. However, I thought of three other nouns (there are probably a few more) that can refer to groups of people – *group*, *society*, and *clique* – and the preposition *in* sounds more natural than the preposition *on* for those nouns.

> - Margaret is an active member **in** the Preservation Society.
> - George and Russell are **in** a clique, and Earnest is not.
> - It's too bad Alexi moved away, I liked it when she was **in** the group.

Therefore, I think we can say it's something we must evaluate noun by noun; it's not as simple as saying that "all nouns referring to groups of people take 'on' as a leading preposition."

Clearly there are some overlaps in the definitions of these words; from Macmillan:

> **in** (*prep.*) used for saying what group someone or something is part of
>    *Kenny’s been in the Boy Scouts since he was eight.*
>
> **on** (*prep.*) if someone is on a team, committee, etc., they are a member of it
>   *I’m glad to have a player like you on our team.*

Comment: So? What's the rule? The rule is that there's no rule, isn't it?

Comment: @SergeyZ - In English, that's the one rule you can most often count on.

Comment: Ok, what's the logic behind those differences in preposition usage? Is a society deemed to be something "closed", while a team something "open"? I don't understand

Comment: Prepositions are peculiar that way. It's a fair question: Why are we _in_ a club but _on_ a team? Or _in_ a guild but _on_ a school board? I'm not really sure. For that matter, why are we _on_ a train but _in_ a car? Or _on_ a sofa but _in_ a chair? And why might a bridge be _in_ the city but _on_ the peninsula? Sometimes it's just the way we say it.